# Error: Uncaught (in promise): true in jasmine test case for Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm new to angular unit testing , was trying to fix the already existing unit test case which fails the error that I getting is   **Error: Uncaught (in promise): true**

The code for the unit test case is as follows

```
  it('ngOnInit', fakeAsync(() => {
        // fixture.detectChanges();
        component.ngOnInit();
        tick();
        expect(component.dataConfig.industries.length).toEqual(3);
        expect(component.dataConfig.fonts.length).toEqual(2);
      }));
```

now within ngOnInit a call is made to the function  which is as below

```
checkUserRole=()=>{
    const requiredRoles = ['admin','developer'];
     this.hasAdminRole = this.service.checkRequiredRoles(
      requiredRoles,
      false
    );
  }
```

and within the spec.ts file they have created the stub and provided it in the provider as below

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ClientConfigComponent],
      imports: [TestingModule, ngfModule, MatDialogModule,
        MaterialModule,
        FormsModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        SharedModule
      ],
      providers: [{
        provide: MatDialogRef,
        useValue: mockDialogRef
      }, {
        provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {}
      },
      { provide: HttpClient, useClass: FakeHttpService },
      {
        provide: MasterService,
        useValue: masterService
      }
      ]
    })
```

Stub

```
const masterService = {
    loadTranslationConfiguration(): any {
      return of({});
    },
    checkRequiredRoles: (requiredRoles, arg) => ({}),
    saveTag(): any {
        return of(saveTags);
    },
    
  };
```

Error in detail

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): true
        error properties: Object({ rejection: true, promise: [object Promise], zone: Zone({ _parent: Zone({ _parent: null, _name: '<root>', _properties: Object({  }), _zoneDelegate: _ZoneDelegate({ _taskCounts: Object({ microTask: 0, macroTask: 0, eventTask: 0 }), zone: <circular reference: Object>, _parentDelegate: null, _forkZS: null, _forkDlgt: null, _forkCurrZone: null, _interceptZS: null, _interceptDlgt: null, _interceptCurrZone: null, _invokeZS: null, _invokeDlgt: null, _invokeCurrZone: null, _handleErrorZS: null, _handleErrorDlgt: null, _handleErrorCurrZone: null, _scheduleTaskZS: null, _scheduleTaskDlgt: null, _scheduleTaskCurrZone: null, _invokeTaskZS: null, _invokeTaskDlgt: null, _invokeTaskCurrZone: null, _cancelTaskZS: null, _cancelTaskDlgt: null, _cancelTaskCurrZone: null
```

I tried returning true from the stub of checkRequiredRoles using the **of** operator of the observable still it gave me same issue,I tried returning the promise the checkRequiredRoles method in service and using .then in stub it gave undefined checkRequiredRoles().then

I'm somewhat sure that error is with checkRequiredRoles function returning  a boolean value and not a promise

```
public checkIfCurrentUserHasRequiredRoles(
    role: string[],
    RequiredRole: boolean
  ): boolean {
    
    //Some Logic

    return isTrue;
  }
```

What should i do to fix this issue where i'm going wrong ,thanks in advance for help

Comment: Is ```this.service``` an alias for ```masterService```? Also ```of``` is not a replacement for a promise, but an observable. If the functions you are mocking out originally return a promise, you should replace ```of``` with ```new Promise((resolve) => resolve())```

Comment: yes this.service is alias for masterService ,and I tried returning resolve from the promise but no luck still same issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong, but I can answer your question of "What should i do to fix this issue where i'm going wrong?"

**Strongly type your properties and function return values.**

In your component:

```js
public hasAdminRole: boolean;

public checkUserRole(): void =>{
  const requiredRoles = [
    'admin',
    'developer'
  ];
  this.hasAdminRole = this.service.checkRequiredRoles(
    requiredRoles,
    false
  );
}
```

(or type hasAdminRole as `Promise<boolean>` or `Observable<boolean>`)

In the masterService stub:

```js
const masterService: Partial<MasterService> = {
  loadTranslationConfiguration: () => of({}),

  checkRequiredRoles: (requiredRoles, arg) => ({}),

  saveTag: () => of(saveTags) // wherever defined, make sure saveTags is strictly typed, too!
};
```

The return type of `checkIfCurrentUserHasRequiredRoles` is already declared.

You mentioned `checkRequiredRoles` but don't list it. Make sure that it's variables and return type are strongly typed as well.

If you do this and can't compile it, you have probably found your answer. Otherwise, you're much farther along in finding the issue *and* you've both documented and strengthened the code without runtime performance impact because all the Typescript checks are done at compile time.

Ask 100 Angular developers how much you should strongly type your code and you'll get at least 150 opinions, but in times like these where part of what you're doing is trying to isolate what it's *not*, I highly recommend it as the starting point because whether or not it was the problem, you are still making a permanent improvement and contribution to the code base.